# Are Mac OS X 10.4.10 install discs model specific like 10.3?

Tags: macos, powerpc, ibook

I have some iBook G4 10.3.3 install and restore discs. I'm not sure if these are actually model specific but since they are labelled as iBook discs I assume they are. Is this true? Also, are 10.4.10 discs model specific? Are there specific discs for Intel/PowerPC? I am trying to install Tiger on an A1134 iBook and I don't want to waste money on discs that will not work.

Comment: Most Mac OSX Installer CDs & DVDs which came with laptops/desktops are model specific, and you can tell because the model is indicated on the disc. Apple sold generic installer discs [like this one](https://www.ebay.com/c/127897616?iid=363186468393) which you might want to take a look at. 10.5.x is the latest Mac OSX which can be installed on this particular iBook

Comment: The iBook has 10.5 installed currently but I need to downgrade it to 10.4 which I believe it shipped with and so should work. The disc I am looking to purchase are just labelled "For Mac computers" like this https://i.pinimg.com/originals/97/37/22/9737227525410425e75d2c3f55cd386b.jpg. I'm not sure if there's also a PowerPC/Intel issue.